# After Deploy App is not connecting to postgres anymore

Tags: postgresql, heroku, strapi, heroku-postgres

after deploying my changes to heroku my strapi app isn't starting anymore.

```
[2020-11-10T15:47:29.476Z] debug :no_entry:️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
2020-11-10T15:47:29.479699+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-10T15:47:29.479Z] error error: password authentication failed for user "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Checked the ENVs everything looks fine but it is not working.
I saw that postgresql updated my database, since that point it is broken.

```
heroku-postgresql: Update DATABASE by heroku-postgresql
Today at 4:22 PM · v34
```

Please help me can´t do anything rn.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now.  Will follow up with any insights.

Comment: would be curious to see your database config file, too.

Comment: Are you using heroku postgres (https://www.heroku.com/postgres)? If so, here they talk about it: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3094.